# $\frac{1280}{m(n+1)}=n^n$ then $m=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\dfrac{1280}{m(n+1)}=n^n$ then $m=?$

So this problem recently appeared in a mathematics competition I attended. This question was the only one I didn't know how to do, can someone please explain the answer to me?

Comment: Is the RHS $n^n$ or $n^nm$?

Comment: n to the n. Sorry if the question wasn't clear, I don't know how to write the equations down in Math Stack Exchange

Comment: Check out the MathJax tutorial.

Comment: "interchange" $n^n$ and $m$

Comment: @BrianBlumberg : with 136 points you should know mathJax, cite the competition name, which competition it is from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start by looking at $n^n$ for a few values of $n$:

- Consider $n=1$: $n^n=1^1=1$.
- Consider $n=2$: $n^n=2^2=4$.
- Consider $n=3$: $n^n=3^3=27$.
- Consider $n=4$: $n^n=4^4=256$.
- Consider $n=5$: $n^n=5^5=3125$.

Therefore, the only possibilities for $n$ are $1,2,3,4$ as all others are greater than $1280$.  Then,
$$
m=\frac{1280}{n^n(n+1)}.
$$
It's not too hard to check each of the $n$'s above to see what happens.  In this case:

- When $n=1$, $m=640$.
- When $n=2$, the fraction is not an integer ($3$ does not divide $1280$).
- When $n=3$, the fraction is not an integer ($3$ does not divide $1280$).
- When $n=4$, $m=1$.

Therefore, it appears that there are two solutions, $m=640$ and $m=1$.

Answer (score 3):

If you prime factorize $1280$:
$$\dfrac{1280}{m(n+1)}=n^n \Rightarrow m=\frac{4^4\cdot 5}{n^n\cdot (n+1)}.$$
Obviously, $n$ can not be greater than $4$, otherwise it becomes an improper fraction (not an integer).

Easy to see that $n$ can only be $1$ and $4$.

Easy to see that $n$ can not be $2$ or $3$, because the numerator is not divisible by $3$.